# Error while doing node js: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Hope u all are doing fine. My question is that whenever i am trying to create a navigation bar and serve that navigation bar on my server it is responding with error 404 not found, but i have placed my logo file in the same directory where my code is the html code is:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Discord Chat</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="logo.png">
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
            }

            #logo {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                border-radius: 30px;
            }

            .navbar ul{
                position: sticky;
            }

            .navbar ul li a{
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: none;
                color: lightseagreen;
            }

            .navbar ul li{
                list-style: none;
                display: inline;
                position: relative;
                top: -30px;
                left: 71px;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .navbar{
                background-color: black;
                opacity: 0.6;
            }

            .navbar ul li:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 50px;
                animation-name: navanim;
                animation-duration: 5s;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            @keyframes navanim{
                from{
                    background-color: white;
                    color: black;
                }
                to{
                    background-color: black;
                    color: white;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="Discord Chat" id="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my server side code is:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
const port = 8000;


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`Server is listening on https://127.0.0.1:${port}/ `);
});
```

any ideas from which i can display my logo in my web

Comment: If you delete the following lines:
`    <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Discord Chat" id="logo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>`
it all works well? Also, I think you have a typo in your question: `sendfile` -> `sendFile`

Comment: hey this is navbar and i cant delete nav bar and there is no type i have checked

Comment: I'm am proposing to delete it only for troubleshooting purposes...

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set up express to serve static files. According to it's doc - something like:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Would serve files from a directory 'public' relative to where the code is.
More information is available at https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html.

You will need to not shortcut the import of express. So the first lines of your code should have:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
```

(Instead of `var app = require('express')();`)

Comment: I was searching this on google also this worked and also i found another trick that instead of filename place full path but in both the case i get a error that Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/Creations/Languages/HTml/HTML/Discord%20Chat/logo.png

Comment: The full path trick will only work if serving HTML from a local filesystem and not a server on a port (when you run node.js, it's a server on a port, even a local one). It also wouldn't serve to anyone else. The HTML, CSS, and paths there are used by the user's browser. The public directory is served by the node server.

Comment: so how can i server from a local file system

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If your app will be dynamic, then carry on with Node and express.js, using the static files. If the app is fairly static, consider a plain web server - nginx/apache.

Comment: Actual thing is that i am beginner in the world of backend and i am following a tutorial of SOCKET.io to create a real time chat application and in that i am getting this error and i don't want to use XAMPP or apache server i am running this on my localhost at port 80

Comment: Ok - stick with the express.static. It will mean you'll need to collect the static files in that place.

Comment: that also is not working now it is showing me unresolved reference express in app.use(express.static('public'))

Comment: Ah - you are shortcutting how you import express - I've updated the answer to help with that.

Comment: I tried both the possibilities, serving static files with full path gives me a error that not allowed to use resource and with only name it says 404 not found, but my all the files are in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Since you are keeping your logo file in the same folder where the other files are present you can try to use it this way.

express.static(__dirname).

Comment: can you explain a bit in detail and in which line on js file i apply this chage

Comment: You can use it just before any route configuration like below.
app.use(express.static(__dirname));